# How can I use `pgffor` to iterate through a database of keys and properly retrieve them

Tags: pgfkeys, pgffor

I would like to create a command that stores a database.  I then want to iterate over the database and *print out* the results to the document.  This MWE shows two different approaches I've taken.  But neither works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/ae/breakfast/menu/.cd,
  fruit/.initial = grape fruit,
  bread/.initial = English muffin,
  eggs/.initial  = hard boiled,
}

\def\allrecords{%%'
  { fruit=apple, 
    bread=bagel,
    eggs=scrambled
  },
  { fruit=orange, 
    bread=toast,
    eggs=fried
   }
  }

\def\aeget#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/breakfast/menu/#1}}

\def\whatIordered{ I ordered \aeget{fruit}, \aeget{bread}, and \aeget{eggs}.}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\whatIordered

%<approach 1>% this fails: "whitespace" getting in the way
%%\foreach \x in \allrecords {\pgfkeys{/ae/breakfast/menu/.cd,\x}\whatIordered\newline}

%<approach 2>% this also fails: keys are misread
%%\foreach \x in \allrecords {\foreach \y in \x {\pgfkeys{/ae/breakfast/menu/\y}} \whatIordered\newline}

\end{document}
```

Is there a means of using `pgfkeys` and then *iterating* over a database?

Comment: Although this may be a moot point, database management of this kind is well-handled by [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply an expansion issue.

If you define

```
\pgfkeys{style/.style={#1}}
```

you can use `/style/.expanded=\something` so that `\something` gets expanded *before* `pgfkeys` parses it.

Comment: Also using `/.estyle` makes it easier and gives a slightly better control over expansion context